# Check if array has the same number of even and odd values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Task:
Complete the following function that determines if the number of even and odd values in an list of Integers is the same.

```
| In               | Out   |         Why            |
|------------------|-------|------------------------|
| [5, 1, 0, 2]     | true  | two evens and two odds |
| [5, 1, 0, 2, 11] | false | too many odds          |
| []               | true  | both have 0            |
```

The function should not affect the contents of the list.

My code:

```
def balanced(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return False
    if n % 2 == 0:
        count_1 = 0
        count_2 = 0
        for item in lst:
            if item % 2 == 0:      #even
                count_1 += 1
            if item % 2 != 0:       #odd
                count_2 += 1
    if count_1 == count_2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def result(lst):
     if balanced(lst):
         print("Your list is successfully balanced! It has same number of evens and odds!!")
     else:
         print("Oh no! Sorry! Your list seems to be not balanced! Try another list please!")
def main():
     lst_1 = [1,2,3,5,6,8,5,9]
     lst_2 = []
     lst_3 = [2,4,5,7]
     lst_4 = [1,2,4,4]
     lst_5 = [1,2,3]
     result(lst_1)
     result(lst_2)
     result(lst_3)
     result(lst_4)
     result(lst_5)
main()
```

Comment: I don't think this deserves its own answer, but I didn't see any others mention it: your code would be a lot more readable if you inserted a new line after logically grouped parts of your code, such as the end of functions.

Comment: A lot of people are trying to "improve" your code be trading readability for small gains in performance. I want to tell you - please don't think that that is what your Python code should look like. Your code should be first of all readable. IF and only IF that part of your codebase turns out to be a bottleneck, ONLY THEN optimize it! Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: This question inspired [Check if an array (or equivalent) has the same number of odd and even numbers - Code Golf Edition!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/205103) - various languages, smallest code challenge

Answer (score 24):

There's no need to keep counts at all.  All you need to do is keep track of whether the sequence is balanced or not as you check every element.  And the special tests you had for an empty list or odd list length are redundant.

```
def balanced(lst):
    tilt = 0
    for item in lst:
        if item % 2 == 0:      #even
            tilt += 1
        else:                  #odd
            tilt -= 1
    return tilt == 0
```

Or if you prefer terseness over readability, you can turn it into a one-liner.

```
def balanced(lst):
    return sum(1 if item % 2 else -1 for item in lst) == 0
```

Comment: Indeed. I wrote `tilt += 1 - 2 * (item % 2)`, which is shorter but probably less readble.

Comment: @EricDuminil definitely less readable.  I considered `item & 1` but that would have been even worse.  The whole function could be condensed to one line: `return sum(1 - 2 * (item & 1) for item in lst) == 0`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'd just use a turnery, much clearer `1 if item % 2 else -1`.

Comment: @Peilonrayz or you can go old-school: `item % 2 or -1`. That's how you did it before they introduced ternaries into Python. There's 100 variations on this problem.

Comment: I look at your code and I see that it is more elegant than the original code. But still, I can glance over OPs code and know what it does, booting up only the dumbest part of my brain.  This submission gives me just that tiny bit of extra resistance :-/

Comment: @epa095 I thought being simpler would make it easier to understand, but obviously not in your case.  That's OK.  Code readability is a highly personal thing.

Comment: @MarkRansom Its shorter, not simpler (although I do agree that "simple" is a subjective notion). If I show you a pile of apples and oranges and asks you if there are equally many of them, what do you do? I would count oranges and apples respectibly and compare. I would not keep a single variable (tilt) which I let go above and below zero until I finally check if it is zero. It takes just that tiny bit of extra mental effort to handle the `tilt` variable, which can be both negative and positive, and the fact that it is zero iff the two amounts are equal.

Comment: I think OP's check on the length of the list was useful to produce the answer much faster (for half the cases). Why get rid of it? It's just two lines of code.

Comment: @Thanassis it prevents you from passing a generic iterator into the function rather than a list.  Fewer constraints are usually a good thing.

Comment: Sure, that's true but the OP seems to be handling lists. By making it more flexible you are losing the performance feature of OP's solution.

Comment: @Thanassis: first make it work, then make it fast.  Less code, less chance for bugs.

Comment: Testing for odd length isn't necessary for correctness, but it could be a useful early-out optimization.  I don't see a special case for empty lists, just a redundant check for `n%2 == 0` after already ruling out the `!= 0` case.

Comment: @PeterCordes you're right about the empty list!  I guess I was confused by the second `if`, since it's checking for a condition that's already guaranteed to be true.  I still stand by my assertion that testing for an odd length is counter-productive, even if it leads to a faster result in some cases.

Comment: Depends on the use-case.  Sure it's often not necessary or useful to optimize at the expense of having more code, and your description of it as "redundant" is not wrong.  If this operation over large lists (for which an early out would matter a lot) was an overall bottleneck in a real-world program, the best solution would probably not be to micro-optimize this with an early out.  e.g. update a `tilt` stored with the array when you change an element so you don't need to scan the whole array, or other kinds of caching or an even larger redesign.

Comment: It's a plain bad idea to use a tilt variable here. It's one less line of code, but way harder to figure out for a reader. If this were C - fine, for the sake of performance, I guess a tilt variable approach is ok. But this is Python, the readability language. Readability > one less line of code. You don't condense a 20 LOC into a 500 char list comprehension just because you can, do you? Neither should we do a fewest-line-of-code competition here.

Comment: @kangalioo I'm afraid I must disagree, this form is more readable to me than the original in the question.  It distills the concept of "balance" down to its essence.  Imagine a balance scale, and you're dropping items on to one side or the other depending on if they're odd or even.  You will never know the exact count on either side of the scale, nor will you care.

Comment: this is one of the only answers that works on generators and not strict lists, because it doesn't rely on len(lst) being implemented. It could also be constructed using a map if for some reason you don't like generators: `sum(map(lambda n: 1 if n%2 else -1, lst)) == 0`

Comment: I actually think that the on-liner using the generator expression is *more* readable because it concisely yet explicitly describes what is being computed. The first solution describes the exact same idea (albeit using a slightly different logic), just more verbosely.

Comment: @KonradRudolph that's why I presented both forms.  I thought that having a variable named `tilt` would make it clear what was being calculated, but I see that some still find it confusing.

Comment: Your description disagrees with your code. You say "no need to keep counts at all", but then you count how many more or fewer evens there are. And you say "All you need to do is keep track of whether the sequence is balanced or not", i.e., boolean, but that's not what you keep track of.

Comment: @superbrain what I meant and perhaps didn't do a good enough job of explaining, is that there's no need to keep a total count of the evens and a total count of the odds.  The integer you see in my code isn't keeping a count, it goes both up and down.

Answer (score 12):

There are a few optimizations that seem obvious to me, but the algorithm seems fine for what is does.

```
if n % 2 != 0:
    return False
if n % 2 == 0:
    # ...
```

There is no need for the second `if` statement, as you already know that `n % 2 == 0` is `True`, as you would have returned otherwise.

```
if item % 2 == 0:      #even
    count_1 += 1
if item % 2 != 0:       #odd
    count_2 += 1
```

You should use an `if ... else` construct, if the number isn't even, then it is odd. This makes one less check for each item.

```
if count_1 == count_2:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

You can simply `return count_1 == count_2`. This simplifies the code and saves a branch, making it slightly more efficient.

You could also use more meaningful variable names, and include a docstring documentating what the code does

Here is my take on your code:

```
def balanced(lst):
    '''Checks if a list contains the same amount of even and odd numbers'''

    if len(lst) % 2 != 0:
        return False
    count_even = 0
    count_odd = 0
    for item in lst:
        if item % 2 == 0:
            count_even += 1
        else: 
            count_odd += 1
    return count_even == count_odd
```

You could probably trim the code even more, for example using only one variable for counting, adding `1` on even numbers and subtracting `1` on odd numbers, and returning whether that value is `0`, but I feel like it would affect negatively the readability.

Comment: I like this. Its less clever than many others, but it retains a property I liked about the original code; it takes me a single glance over it to know exactly what it does, while removing some of the obvious eye-sores.

Comment: @epa095 I feel like its a common issues with python. A lot of things can be turned into nifty one-liners, but it defeats one of the purposes of the language: it's designed to be readable.

Comment: @epa095 - In my opinion, 'Cleverness' in code is a drawback, not a benefit.  Simplicity and Readability are the things that really matter 99% of the time.

Answer (score 10):

- You don't need `count_1` and `count_2` just one count.

  $$
  \begin{align}
      \text{even}\ + \text{odd} &= \text{length}\\
      \text{even}\ = \text{odd} &= \text{count}\\
      \therefore 2\text{count} &= \text{length}
  \end{align}
  $$
- You can just `return <exp>` rather than

  ```py
  if <exp>:
      return True
  else:
      return False
  ```
- You don't need the first `if n % 2 == 0:` check.

```py
def balanced(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return False
    count = 0
    for item in lst:
        if item % 2 == 1:
            count += 1
    return 2 * count == n
```

- You can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and a comprehension to create `count`.
  If we build a list of counts then we can see how `sum` works with lists:

  ```py
  counts = []
  for item in lst:
      if item % 2 == 1:
          counts.append(1)
  count = sum(counts)
  ```

  This should make sense as it's just totalling all the values. From here we can use some sugar to build a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
  This would look like:

  ```py
  counts = [
      1
      for item in lst
      if item % 2 == 1
  ]
  count = sum(counts)
  ```

  You should see that it builds the list with a lot less noise. Making code quicker to read and more minimalistic.

  From here we can merge them all into one line, and convert the list comprehension to an implicit [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

  ```py
  count = sum(1 for item in lst if item % 2 == 1)
  ```
- You can remove the `if` as `item % 2` is either 1 or 0, and so summing will provide the count of odd numbers.
- I would prefer seeing `items` or `values` rather then `lst`

```py
def balanced(items):
    if len(items) % 2 != 0:
        return False
    count = sum(i % 2 for i in items)
    return 2 * count == len(items)
```

If we remove your well thought out optimization, then we can put this on one line:

```py
def balanced(items):
    return len(items) == 2 * sum(i % 2 for i in items)
```

Comment: What is the content in this new sum function  "sum(.....)" called? Does this function come under advanced courses of python?

Comment: @UncalledAstronomer I do not know what you mean by context. It's a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). I have not followed any Python courses and so I do not know what 'level' it is. However I personally would say it's either beginner/basic or not included in your course.

Comment: @UncalledAstronomer it's technically a generator expression. If you look them up, their content is the same as list comprehensions, but they're surrounded by parentheses. If they're used as the only argument to a function, like what's going on here in the call to ``sum``, then instead of having two sets of parentheses (one for the function call, one for the generator expression), you can discard the redundant parenthesis and get what you see above.

Comment: @EricDuminil B-but, [mine is one pass](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)! ;)

Comment: In general an either-or per-element classification should be optimized for count one thing and calculate the other from `y = length - x` after the loop.  This optimization isn't limited to cases where you're looking for balanced.  E.g. if you just want to return both odd and even counts you should still only count one in the loop (or list comprehension).  But yes, optimizing it to `2*count_odd == len` is good.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm don't understand you. Do you have a problem with the changes I've made? The first part of your comment sounds like you do, but you say "But yes, ... is good" at the end.

Comment: I'm only expanding on the point you made;  you went straight from the `odd + even = length` to `odd * 2 = length` without pointing out the general-case idea of sinking one counter out of the loop.  I thought that's a useful point to make that's applicable to more situations, which future readers (including the OP) could benefit from remembering, and thus maybe useful for your answer to cover somewhere in that early stuff about only counting one thing.  So I'm suggesting changes to your text, not your code.

Comment: Sorry but what you did was minifying the code, not bettering it. This code is not a comprehensible description of its purpose, it's just a logic riddle.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the explanation, I now understand you. However I don't really understand why rearranging the first equation to \$\text{even} = \text{length} - \text{odd}\$ and adding it to the three at the beginning is helpful. My answers are long already, if I were to address ever alternate everyone involved in my answers would go insane.

Comment: @kangalioo Many things in programming follow the idea that less is more. The less code, the less time it takes to read, the more we can solve other problems. However it would be interesting to see how you would better the code. Care to enlighten me?

Comment: @Peilonrayz I wanna excuse for me extremely negative comment of your solution. I've realized every answer is helpful than no answer, because all answers give a new perspective onto the problem. _Anyway_, [this is how I would do it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242688/220605)

Answer (score 7):

Do not use recursion for simple use cases like this one (OP has asked about this in the original, unedited question)!
It can be done simply, as shown below.
First, a walkthrough:

A construct like

```py
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return False
    if n % 2 == 0:
```

can be simplified by omitting the second `if` statement, since you return early anyway.
This saves a whole level of indentation:

```py
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return False
    count_1 = 0
    ...
```

If you did not return and thus exit but instead did something else, use an `else` clause to avoid repeating yourself, which might introduce subtle errors and bugs.
Instead do:

```py
   if n % 2 != 0:
       <something other than return>
   else:
       count_1 = 0
```

---

Further, this

```py
    if count_1 == count_2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

can just be

```py
return count_1 == count_2
```

---

In your code, you loop over the list manually.
This can be replaced by (faster) list comprehension.
In fact, it can be a one-liner altogether, while still being readable:

```py
def balanced(lst):
    return len([number for number in lst if number % 2 == 0]) == len(lst) / 2
```

This works without your `if n % 2 != 0` guard clause, because an uneven list length divided by `2` (`len(lst) / 2`) will never return an integer (gives `float` with non-zero decimal part), and therefore always compare unequal to the left side.

The left side is a list comprehesion that simply gets all even numbers in the sequence.
It could also grab all uneven ones.
This will always be an integer.

This solution is faster and reasonably Pythonic.
It does not treat the special case of a list of odd length.

Keeping it speeds up the code however.
The following is roughly 20% faster than the above one-liner:

```py
from timeit import timeit

def balanced(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return False
    return len([number for number in lst if number % 2 == 0]) == n / 2

def main():
    test_lists = [
        [5, 1, 0, 2],
        [5, 1, 0, 2, 11],
        [],
        [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 5, 9],
        [2, 4, 5, 7],
        [1, 2, 4, 4],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2],
        [1],
        [0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 2, 2],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        # ["hello"], # error
    ]
    for test_list in test_lists:
        # print(balanced(test_list), test_list, sep=":\t")
        balanced(test_list)

print(timeit("main()", globals=globals()))
```

Uncommenting `print(balanced(test_list), test_list, sep=":\t")` and just running `main()` without timing, it prints:

```py
True:   [5, 1, 0, 2]
False:  [5, 1, 0, 2, 11]
True:   []
False:  [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 5, 9]
True:   [2, 4, 5, 7]
False:  [1, 2, 4, 4]
False:  [1, 2, 3]
True:   [1, 2]
False:  [1]
False:  [0]
False:  [1, 1, 1, 1]
True:   [1, 1, 2, 2]
False:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: @Peilonrayz Thank you, I am well aware! In the original question, OP had asked for a recursive solution.

Comment: Indeed they did in the original title. Might I suggest you [edit] your answer to clarify that for future readers.

Comment: I [benchmarked](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242697/220605) the answers and your code is the fastest of them all! 10% faster even than [Peilonrayz' answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242565/220605) which heavily traded readability for performance

Comment: @kangalioo Interesting, thanks for putting it together. I guess that is all down to our highly optimized lord and savior, list comprehensions.

Answer (score 6):

I made a benchmark. The test data is a Python list with 1,000,000 numbers between 1 and 30 (inclusive). I've tested every answer that has been given so far:

```
0.044s mean time - balanced_alex_2
0.047s mean time - balanced_alex
0.050s mean time - balanced_peilonrayz
0.060s mean time - balanced_mark
0.061s mean time - balanced_delta
0.065s mean time - balanced_mti2935
0.066s mean time - balanced_kangalioo_expanded
0.154s mean time - balanced_kangalioo_compact
0.178s mean time - balanced_anonymous
```

[Benchmark code](https://pastebin.com/37Xsfqej)

The top two answers by Mark and Peilonrayz carelessly traded readability in an attempt to gain speed - only somewhat successfully as you can see. Alex' answers dominate the benchmark instead.

My answers went all in on readability, while disregarding performance. You can see that even my answer is in the same ballpark as the optimized version from Alex.

Even Alex' code is not as fast as you can go, though. Changing the code to use a NumPy array yields a mean runtime of 0.011s for Numpy - 4x faster than the fastest Python answer.

Conclusion; if you need

- best performance and ok readability => Numpy
- ok performance and bad readability => [Alex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242570/220605)
- acceptable performance and best readability => [kangalioo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242688/220605)

Comment: “The top two answers by Mark and Peilonrayz carelessly traded readability in an attempt to gain speed” — That’s explicitly *not* what Mark’s doing.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good candidate for **list comprehensions**.

Here is some proposed code (not the most compact but should be fairly easy to understand):

```
from typing import List

def is_even(number: int) -> bool:
    return (number % 2) == 0


def balanced(lst: List)-> bool:

    # list empty: return True by choice
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return True

    return len([item for item in lst if is_even(item)]) == len([item for item in lst if not is_even(item)])

# testing
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(f'List: {lst1} - balanced: {balanced(lst1)}')
```

---

For convenience I have defined an additional function `is_even`.

Logic: count the even numbers, do the same with odd numbers and if both sets have the same length, return True.
I am not verifying that all items in the list are `int`...

Comment: As a note, this makes two full lists, whereas the filtering conditions for the lists are mutually exclusive. That means we could omit one of the two (if a number is not even, it is automatically uneven) and still reach the same result. That saves [a lot of work](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242697/223083).

Answer (score 3):

There are general refactoring lessons to be learned here. First, if you exit in an `if` statement, you don't need what follows to be the opposite of that `if`, because you can only reach that lower code if the original condition is falsy [sic]. The advantage is later code is less deeply nested. Similarly, the ending simplifies. Never return `True` if something and `False` otherwise, just return that something (cast to a `bool` if necessary). This insight simplifies your original logic for `balanced` to

```
def balanced(lst):
    if len(lst) % 2 != 0: return False
    count_1 = 0
    count_2 = 0
    for item in lst:
        if item % 2 == 0: count_1 += 1
        if item % 2 != 0: count_2 += 1
    return count_1 == count_2
```

(Note the guard clause meant we no longer needed to cache what you called `n`.) While the remaining pair of if statements could be an if/else instead, at this point it's worth simplifying with the mathematical insight others mentioned:

```
def balanced(lst):
    if len(lst) % 2: return False
    evens_minus_odds = 0
    for item in lst:
        evens_minus_odds += 1 if item % 2 == 0 else -1
    return evens_minus_odds == 0
```

Suddenly, you can't help but make it declarative instead of imperative:

```
def balanced(lst):
    return len(lst) % 2 == 0 and sum(1 if item % 2 == 0 else -1 for item in lst) == 0
```

Which is basically what everyone else got. Well, not everyone even bothered including the first check: it saves time for odd-length lists, but that's premature optimization because it'd be neater still to write

```
def balanced(lst):
    return sum(1 if item % 2 == 0 else -1 for item in lst) == 0
```

(Incidentally, `1 if item % 2 == 0 else -1` could also be replaced with `(-1) ** (item %2)`.)

What have we learned?

- Long imperative code is often crying out to become short declarative code;
- Refactoring what little you can at first will gradually give you new ideas;
- Boolean logic cries out for simplification. It just so happens your code had no bugs, but the anti-if campaign exists because many aren't so lucky. I'm a big advocate of making code more declarative, in part because it makes it harder to create, or at least miss, certain bugs.

Comment: Hmm you may have gone slightly overboard swinging the axe now; but it’’s definitely a good, concise answer.

Answer (score 2):

A response to the answerers on here so far: if you want best performance, use a C extension. If you want readability, use this:

```py
def balanced(lst):
    num_even = sum(item % 2 == 0 for item in lst)
    num_odd = sum(item % 2 == 1 for item in lst)
    return num_even == num_odd
```

This is *readable* AND compact AND probably decently fast. The only thing that might be hard-to-understand, especially for new Python programmers, is the `sum(<generator>)` construct. You can also expand that construct for better accessibility for new programmers:

```py
def balanced(lst):
    num_even = 0
    num_odd = 0
    for number in lst:
        if number % 2 == 0: # even
            num_even += 1
        else: # odd
            num_odd += 1
    return num_even == num_odd
```

These code snippets are very concise and clear, in contrast to the currently most-upvoted answers:

The top answer right now uses a special `tilt` variable. That seems to me like a cryptic trick just for the purpose of using one less variable. Why? We have lots of variables to spare. It's hard-to-understand AND not compact AND probably not even faster than the naive solution.

The second top answer right now uses mathematical tricks to prove that you only need to count half of the numbers to do the checking. That person is probably a great mathematician. Please don't code like that, though. At least not without commenting your hard-to-understand intent.

The most important metric to keep in mind while coding, especially in a language like Python, is readability. Like 99% of your codebase won't ever be a performance issue - and if performance is not an issue, the top priority is readability (after correctness, of course).

Answer (score 2):

#### collections.Counter

I'm surprised `Counter()` hasn't been mentioned yet.  It's raison d'être is to count things.  Using `Counter()` results in a short easy to read function:

```
from collections import Counter

def is_balanced(seq):
    '''determines if seq has equal numbers of odd/even items'''

    count = Counter(item % 2 for item in seq)

    return count[0] == count[1]
```

It's not the fastest of the alternatives, but the performance is probably acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a compact way of doing it, without using any loops or if statements.

```
lst = [1,2,3,5,6,8,5,9,4,6]

def balanced(lst):
    return(sum(map(lambda x: x%2, lst))==0.5*len(lst))

print(balanced(lst))
```

The `map` function creates a new list consisting of 1's and 0's corresponding to each element in the input list.  1 means the corresponding element is odd, 0 means the corresponding element is even.  Then, the `sum` function is used to add up all the elements in the resulting list from the `map` fucntion.  This tells us the number of odd elements in the original list.  The result of the sum function is then compared to half the number of elements in the original list.  If the comparison is equal, this means that there are an equal number of odd and even elements in the original list.

Comment: `map` and `lambda` (for filtering) are often better replaced by (list) comprehension, which is usually found to be more readable and often faster (when [passing `lambda` that is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948713/11477374)). `map` and `lambda`, among other things, were even supposed to be [removed for Python 3](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196). So they work, but aren't "pythonic", which is not entirely objective, of course.

Comment: In this case, using `sum(map(lambda x: x%2 or -1, lst))` might be nicer (no float comparison and tells which and how many wrong elements there are). If one wants a bool, `return not bool()` of the above will work.

Comment: Map is discouraged by Guido and deprecated by Google. Additionally the Pythonic solution to this is comprehensions as explained by Alex Povel. This is bad advice, it still has a loop too...

Comment: @Peilonrayz It’s worth noting that the Google style guide explicitly says the usage `map(f, seq)` is OK. Only `map(lambda …, seq)` is discouraged.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Indeed it does say something like that. I'm not sure it applies here as even if you were to remove the `lambda` I'm not sure the author would be happy seeing `f = 2..__rmod__` :)

Comment: Also worth noting is that x % 2 == x & 1 in Python. But although it produces different bytecode, it apparently has no effect on speed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597019/which-is-faster-to-find-the-even-number-ifn2-0-or-ifn1-0

Answer (score 1):

There are some interesting ideas raised by this problem, guard clauses (or perhaps we should say short circuits) being one of them, we can extend

```
if len(lst) % 2 != 0: return False
```

with

```
if len(lst) == 0: return True
```

This raises the question (from the point of view of efficiency) which order should they go in?  The answer depends on the expected data.  If empty arrays are very common, we should test for that first, if they are never (or extremely rarely) going to occur we don't need the test.

Since we can't do a good design without some knowledge of the domain, suppose we have to test only ISBN 13s?  In that case we can just write

```
return False
```

Another thing we can do is add a short circuit in the loop, something like:

```
length = len(list) 
for index, item in enumerate(list)
    if (length - index < abs(count) ) return False 
    count += ...
```

Again in most circumstances this is not worth the candle, but if we have billion digit ternary numbers the potential time saving would be considerable!  (We might even decide to sort such an array with the smaller, and hence shorter numbers first.)